# Connecting a Arduino to FT232

Tags: serial, gsm

I found this wonderful breakout board based on [FT232](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716#comment-53e7333cce395f8b068b4567). I wonder if I can use this board for connecting my arduino to a USB dongle for 3g/GPRS connection ?

From what I understand this board can be connected to the serial data pins of the arduino board. And if I connect the USB dongle to the FT232 board, I should be able to run AT commands from the arduino board.

Comment: How exactly do you imagine connecting two USB devices to work?

Comment: Many don't realize that USB has distinct host and device roles; it's a common confusion, but yes, the answer is that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, as the FT232 would have to act as a USB host device. A [USB host shield](http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/usb-host-shield-2-0-for-arduino) might work if someone has written driver code to support 3G modems.